# corrupt folders on ext3 file system, that I cannot open/chown/chmod

Tags: command-line, permissions, filesystem, ext3

Everything, that I do is under root:
When I try to enter (cd) or look inside (ls) of mentioned, problemmatic folders, it gives an error: Operation is not permitted.
So, I checked FS for errors:

```
e2fsck -p -v -f /dev/disk_part
```

It has found some errors, but those files remained unreadable.
I've checked with:

```
e2fsck -p -v -f -cc /dev/disk_part
```

It found bad sectors and marked them and fixed errors on file system.
Than I've reran the e2fsck command without checking for bad sectors several more times. It didn't find any errors any more, but problemmatic folders remained unreadable.

I've checked dir's permissions with:

```
ls -lhd /media/user/disk_part/problemmatic_dirs
```

It gave me different, look-like corrupt options on permission's section and owner/group sections. I will just list permission, user, group sections, since dir names look normal (They are just numeric names):

```
perms/user/group
d--x-----T/419495953/286824925
d--S-----x/277422210/10066365
---------x/412696576/2156502457
d-w-r-----/2509832320/2560212409
d-wS--Sr-x/12058624/2367249341
```

So, there are few more folders with such corrupt pattern, but I think, this is enough for you to see the picture.

Doing:

```
chmod -cR 777 /media/user/disk_part/problemmatic_dirs
```

and/or:

```
chown -cR root:root /media/user/disk_part/problemmatic_dirs
```

Gives an error: Operation not permitted

How can I fix it?

I would prefer to try to recover corrupt folders and delete only as the last resort and only after they were recovered.

```
/media/user/disk_part type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,realtime,data=ordered,uhelper=disks2)
```

it shows ext4, but the partition, I know is ext3.

Comment: How is it mounted? `mount | grep disk_part`

Comment: "/media/user/disk_part type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,realtime,data=ordered,uhelper=disks2)" <- it shows ext4, but the partition, I know is ext3

Comment: Please edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/944582/edit) your question to add information, and format it as well as you did in the rest of your question. I did it for you this time.

Comment: `ext4` is `ext3` plus journalling.

Comment: Inspect your system's logs with `journalctl -b` (Of course, read `man journalctl`).

Comment: I've tried to do journalctl -b, but did not see anything related to these file/folders.